# C# Way to compare DateTime with mask

Tags: c#, datetime, filter, compare, mask

Let's say, we have a `DateTime` with some fields set, ex. only `Month` and `Day`. It's a **mask**. And we want to filter list of DateTimes through this mask:

match X, if X has Month and Day **same as mask**, and any other values in other fields, if mask has them unset (zeros).

Of course, I can do it whth a lot of comparsions for each possible field, but I believe in .NET library. I'm looking for a good way of doing this, either with or without LINQ.

Real-world usage of this is like specifying a year to find all corresponding entries for this year, or specifying month and day to find everything for these month and day (any year and time)

EDIT: I am looking for a native way of telling that dates representing "2010" and "2010/02/01" are in some kind of relationship (basically, "2010" includes "2010/02/01" as more specific). I called "2010" mask previously.

Comment: Are these stored in a collection somewhere? Most collections allow you to implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` or `IComparer<T>`, you could provide an implementation for each of the masks you want to check and supply that. Or have a series of static methods that you give to LINQ `Where` calls.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth: Yes, I know about these things, my question is about native way of comparing DateTimes. I'll include this in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, `DateTime` isn't a good representation of your mask, since it can't have no year, or no month, or no day, etc.  Create a new class to represent your mask that has *nullable* values for each of those properties:

```
public class DateMask
{
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public int? Day { get; set; }
    public int? Month { get; set; }
}
```

(You can add properties for hour, second, timezone, etc as desired.)

Now that we have a mask that clearly holds the important information, composing a query is fairly simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> FilterDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates, DateMask mask)
{
    var query = dates;
    if (mask.Year.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(date => date.Year == mask.Year);
    if (mask.Month.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(date => date.Month == mask.Month);
    if (mask.Day.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(date => date.Day == mask.Day);
    return query;
}
```

(You can follow the pattern to add an `if`/`Where` for additional properties added to the mask.)

(You may want to refactor the method to be an instance method of `DateMask` as well.)

Comment: A clear idea and clean implementation, thank you! But this requires custom class and comparsion. So, there's no native way of determining 'partial equality' of DateTimes?

Comment: @Rast No, there is not, as I stated at the start of the post.  A `DateTime` must represent a specific date and time, it was not designed to represent a mask with some of the values unknown.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

```
        List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>();
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2010, 11, 11));
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2010, 7, 25));
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2011, 5, 11));
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2011, 11, 13));
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2013, 7, 13));
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2013, 1, 13));
        dt.Add(new DateTime(2012, 1, 11));

        string userInputMask = "201_-07-__";
        string mask = userInputMask.Replace("_",@"\d");
        var result = dt.Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(@String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", a), @mask));

        result.ToList().ForEach(a=>Console.WriteLine(a));
```

result:

> 2010-07-25 00:00:00
>
> 2013-07-13 00:00:00

**\d** means a digit. For simplicity, user enters masked digits as e.g. underline character

Comment: crazy or not, it works :) and it's basically 2 lines of code, the rest is just context. Although I don't know if it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Quite elegant and easy to code. On the downside, using regex means poor performance